# `result.isCancelled` + `result.postId` always undefined after cancellation via ShareDialog on Android

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am attempting to utilize the ShareDialog export from the 'react-native-fbsdk' library.

Our implementation (shown below) works perfectly well when the user doesn't have Facebook installed on their device and when they successfully share their photo.

However, when the user begins to share and discards the Facebook window, `result.isCancelled` is only captured on iOS.  `result.postId` isn't populated on either iOS and Android.

Is there something that needs to be done in order for `result.isCancelled` to be populated on Android and/or `result.postId` to be populated on either platform?

```
  ShareDialog.canShow(shareContent).then(
    (canShow) => {
      if (canShow) {
        return ShareDialog.show(shareContent);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
  ).then(
    (result) => {
      if (!result) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'You must have Facebook installed on this device in order to share this post')
      } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        Alert.alert('Cancelled', 'Share cancelled');
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Success!', 'Share successful');
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      Alert.alert(`Share fail with error: ${error}`);
    },
  )
```

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user cancelled?

Comment: When the user *does* successfully post then the `result.postId` does not populate.  If it did then we would be able to determine if a cancellation occurred or not based on whether or not `result.postId` was populated.

`result.isCancelled` is properly populated on iOS;  the issue only persists on Android.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Apologies. Since both `result.isCancelled` and `result.postId` are never populated in Android, there's no way to distinguish whether or not the user successfully posted or cancelled out of the share dialog

Comment: Still doesn't answer my question. Why do you need to know if they successfully posted of cancelled?

Comment: As the code above shows, it will show an alert to the user whether they have successfully posted or not.

Comment: The Facebook dialog will tell the user that too. There is no reason to tell the user again

Comment: This is simply not true while on Android.  If I update the code to remove the `Alerts` then nothing happens after sharing a photo via the Share Dialog.  See the [screen capture linked here](https://photos.google.com/u/1/photo/AF1QipOlrXTPAroL_yfhstiLmx5rHUwDNIIdMbCcMs5j)

Comment: He may not need to tell the user "again", but he very well may need to do something specific in the app layer in response to the user cancelling.  It is perfectly reasonable to need to know if the user stopped an action that was initiated inside of your app

Comment: @MichaelSchlecht: Your link doesn't work for me. Nathan: That was my question. I asked him what he wanted to do based on the information that the user canceled. And the reason for that is there are a bunch of things you could do that is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policies.

Comment: @WizKid here's an updated link: https://youtu.be/L9CIA9wnd0M

I assumed from the code above our intentions were clear.  We want to alert the user in 4 use cases: (1) When they've successfully shared their post. (2) When the user has successfully cancelled out of the Share Dialog. (3) When the user doesn't have Facebook installed. And (4) when an error has occurred.

Comment: @WizKid, thank you for explaining your concerns a bit better, however, I don't think that is what is relevant to Michael's question.  the process works on iOS but not on Android.  It doesn't really matter what they are wanting to do in the app layer, it matters that the functionality isn't the same across platforms.  Android appears to be broken in this regard

Comment: Nathan: Could be that because people are using the feature for things that they shouldn't it was removed on iOS and they haven't just gotten around to remove it on Android yet.

Comment: @WizKid I assume you mean the opposite? Because it sounds like the intended functionality works in iOS but not in Android. Your "solution" seems flawed in theory though as it makes little since to remove a feature without some form of documentation and while only removing it on a single platform.  If you are privy to some piece of documentation that shows this feature is not supported, I am sure that would be more useful than blind speculation. It seems apparent that you don't know how to resolve Michael's solution though so maybe it is time to stop this meaningless conversation?